# Complex TSQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a huge table.  The below is a model of how data is structured into this table.
[image: Structure of the data in the table.]
I need to create a query that returns this dataset.
[image: Query Result]
Let me explain what is the result.  Here I want to select the rows for each distinct value in 'Column1' which has the latest date in 'Column6'.

What is the optimal way to tackle this query.  Recall that the table is huge and I think it is better to avoid JOINS.

Comment: Stop posting picture instead post them text

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you find that meant you needed to ask for advice? see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** to get the top 1 `Column6` descending, for each `Column1`.

```
select 
    Column1
  , Column2
  , Column3
  , Column4
  , Column5
  , Column6
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by Column1
        order by Column6 desc
        )
  from t
  ) as s
where rn = 1
```

**`cross` [`apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** version:

```
 select distinct
     x.*
  from t
    cross apply (
      select top 1
            *
        from t as i
        where i.Column1 = t.Column1
        order by i.[date] desc
       ) as x;
```

**`cross` [`apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** with distinct subquery version:

```
 select 
     x.*
  from (select distinct Column1 from t)
    cross apply (
      select top 1
            *
        from t as i
        where i.Column1 = t.Column1
        order by i.[date] desc
       ) as x;
```

**[`top with ties`](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** version:

```
select top 1 with ties
    *
  from t
  order by row_number() over (
      partition by Column1
      order by Column6 desc
      )
```

Comment: Can you further explain what is happening please. I also think that here you are selecting the first row from each partition which does necessarily have the latest date. I want to select the row with the latest date in each partition.

Comment: Ok sorry you are sorting by Column6 desc. Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try.

Comment: @user2307236 `order by Column6 desc` means that it will order Column6 from highest to lowest, i.e. latest to oldest

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a snippet of code like the following:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column6 DESC) RwNr
    FROM TableName
)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column
FROM CTE
WHERE RwNr = 1;
```

Keep in mind that this uses **windowing functions which are highly performant**.

Some documentation on the subject:

- `ROW_NUMBER()` clause documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx
- `OVER` clause (which you must use when using ranking functions) documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx